# What is the proper way to use sub routines and Functions with error handling?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, error-handling

I have written a ticketing system for the company I work for. We have been running on this software for over a year. I am currently in the middle of updating this software to include a new request form for maintenance. I completely started over from scratch and have programmed everything much better with the idea of never using the same code twice. I am already over three thousand lines of code and I am running into an issue. To use code over again, I am either placing it in a sub routine or a function with parameters. In those sub and function blocks, I am using try catch for error handling. The problem is, I am using these functions all over the place in the application like the splash screen for example. If something errors on the splash screen, the first issue is, the message will be auto closed because the splash screen only shows for a few seconds. The second issue I am having is if you don't click the OK button on the error fast enough before the splash screen closes, it completely freezes the application. Is there a better way of doing this?

I thought about creating a public variable to pass the error too but I am not sure if that is the best way to do it. I want the application to be as professional as possible. I have also thought about creating a error console but I am not quite sure how to do that. I have not tried much because I don't know of a better way to handle this particular issue.

```
Private Sub Splash_Screen_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

## Splash screen Code

## My added code:
Try
'Most of these functions also have a try catch block.
Public_Functions.GetApplicationSettings(Public_Functions.SQL_ApplicationSettingsTable)
Catch EX As Exception

Public_Functions.ShowErrorBox("Unable to load application settings!", EX.Message, MethodPath:=Public_Functions.GetMethodPath())
        End Try

End Sub
```

If the software has an error, I expect it to display the error and wait for the user to close the box on the splash screen, or display the error on the main form after the splash screen closes.

The actual behavior is when the software errors, it will try to display multiple error windows and the splash screen will close which is freezing the application. If my splash screen load events are removed, it will run the application but none of the things I need to load will be available.

Comment: Personally, I try my best to prevent exceptions unless it's really needed. That way, I can write a good message at the right place. Also, having Public_Functions sounds like a dumping class, might want to think of separating things properly in classes.

Comment: These exceptions are usually needed. This application uses SQL to store the data. If the user is not in the correct group to be able to enter and pull data, it will error. It will be situations like that. As far as the public functions goes, it is a module I have created that strictly has project wide code in it. Things I can use no matter what form I am on. If the code is form specific, I just put it in the form. My idea was to never write the same code more than once. If there is a better way to do it, I am open for suggestions. I am just figuring all of this stuff out on my own.

Comment: Can you check security before calling SQL?

Comment: I'm sure I could do that. I'm not sure what would make the difference though. exception or no exception, I think it should still show the message box say what is wrong. The message box is my issue at the moment. Also a note to add, I am not using the standard Messagebox.show(). I created my own using a task dialog. But my experience seems to be the same with task dialog or messagebox.

Comment: Oh! sorry about that, I thought your problem was about handling exceptions. Seems like it's just about showing the message box.

Comment: That and using code in a sub routine that also handles errors. I'm not sure what the best route is. I can make it run properly probably but it would be messy code.

Comment: There's certainly nothing wrong with having a utility function to react to an exception, and for that function to take the exception as an argument.  This sort of thing is commonly done with logging functions.  I'd also note that "Messy code" suggests that your routine might be trying to do too many things and might be appropriate to break up into more than one routine.  (Not a given, but something to think about.)

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed the issue I had. Instead of using the splash screen to load some things I just added a middleman form that loads everything. I tried to find out how to make the splash screen wait until my commands were done but I was unable to find anything other than changing the minimum display time. My app still shows an error for every sub or function but i'm not sure how to get around that. For example, if a certain user is not in the groups they need to be in AD, they will get a message multiple times saying something like cant connect to SQL. I have a lot of subs or functions that pull from SQL that start out with a SQL connect statement. It will show the connection error and the error for each of those subs or functions but as long as they are in the group, its all good.